# Display a picture

Tags: graphics

I am a very new user of Latex, and I am struggling with inserting a picture. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\title{Specifications}
\author{Jérémie Gauthier}
\date{December 6, 2017}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
   \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperRight{\raisebox{-\height}{\frame{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{test.jpeg}}}}}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

First document. This is a simple example, with no 
extra parameters or packages included.
\end{document}
```

Here is my repository

```
total 180
drwxr-xr-x 2 infinity infinity  4096 Dec  3 17:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 infinity infinity  4096 Dec  3 16:11 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 infinity infinity  7926 Dec  3 17:43 3ej.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 infinity infinity  4549 Dec  3 15:49 3ej.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 infinity infinity   186 Dec  3 17:49 specifications.aux
-rw-rw-r-- 1 infinity infinity 23339 Dec  3 17:49 specifications.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 infinity infinity 37670 Dec  3 17:49 specifications.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 infinity infinity  1741 Dec  3 17:49 specifications.synctex.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 infinity infinity   619 Dec  3 17:49 specifications.tex
-rw-rw-r-- 1 infinity infinity 10965 Dec  3 17:48 test.jpeg
```

Why my picture is never showed up? How could I fix it?
Be aware that I am a programmer using Linux.

Comment: you are using `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` the `demo` option stops it using the external images

Comment: Thanks, and how to get rid of the black border of a photo?

Comment: you have added it so just don't add it if you don't want it (`\frame`)

Comment: note what you show is far from the usual way of including an image which would simply be `\includegraphics{test}` with none of your definition, what is the intended effect here?